# Updating a <tr> in Rails via Ajax/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to update my list item after clicking update on my modal.

What I did so far is that I placed an `id` with the `contact.id` on my `<tr>` for reference and then use that on my jQuery / Ajax.

Here's my `_listing.html.erb`:

```
<table class="table" id="contacts">
  <% contacts.each do |contact| %>
    <%= render partial: 'contacts/contact_item', locals: {contact: contact} %>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Here's my `_contact_item.html.erb`:

```
<tr id="contact_item_<%= contact.id %>">
  <td class="middle">
    <div class="media">
      <div class="media-left">
        <%= link_to contact_path(contact), ":data-target" => "#show-contact-modal", ":data-toggle" => "modal", remote: true do %>
            <%= image_tag contact.contact_avatar.attached? ? contact.contact_avatar : "100x100.png", class: "media-object img-thumbnail img-rounded mr-3" %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class="media-body mt-2">
        <%= link_to contact_path(contact), ":data-target" => "#show-contact-modal", ":data-toggle" => "modal", remote: true do %>
             <h4 class="media-heading"><%= contact.name %></h4>
        <% end %>
        <address>
          <strong><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> <%= contact.city %>, <%= contact.state %>, <%= contact.country %>, <%= contact.zip %> </strong><br>
          <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> <%= contact.email %> | <i class="fa fa-mobile"></i> <%= contact.mobile %> | <i class="fa fa-phone"></i> <%= contact.phone %>
        </address>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td class="middle" width="100">
    <div class="mt-5">
    <%= link_to edit_contact_path(contact), class: "btn btn-outline-secondary btn-circle btn-xs", ":data-target" => "#new-contact-modal", ":data-toggle" => "modal", remote: true do %>
          <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
      <% end %>

      <div class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-circle btn-xs delete-contact" data-id="<%= contact.id %>">
        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

And here's my `update.js.erb`:

```
<% if @success %>
  $('#new-contact-modal').modal('hide');
  $("tr#contact_item_<%= contact.id %>").html("<%= j render 'contacts/contact_item', contact: @contact %>");
  toastr.info('Contact was successfully updated.', 'info')
<% else %>
  $(".errors").removeClass('hide');
  <% @contact.errors.messages.each do |record| %>
    <% key = record.first %>
    var html = "<%= j get_error(@contact, key) %>";
    $(".error-<%= key.to_s %>").html(html);
  <% end %>

  $('#save-btn').removeAttr("disabled");

<% end %>
```

Basically, I am trying to close the modal after update but in this case it won't close at all and I need to refresh the page in order to see the update which is not what I am trying to do since I am using ajax and jquery to do no refresh.

Anyone can see what am I missing here?

Comment: It might be more complex than this... but should it be `@contact.id` here: `$("tr#contact_item_<%= contact.id %>").html("<%= j render 'contacts/contact_item', contact: @contact %>");`

Comment: I think its the same code I place above. Still not working though.

Comment: you probably want to render the partial: `<%= j render partial: 'contacts/contact_item', locals: { contact: @contact } %>`

Comment: I tried to prepend and it did close the modal however its adding a duplicate at the top along with the old record. `  $('#contacts').prepend("<%= j render 'contacts/contact_item', contact: @contact %>");`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to hardwire the id - you can just get it from the rendered template. You also don't want to insert the entire rendered view as that would give you:

```
<tr id="contact_item_1">
  <tr id="contact_item_1">
      # ...
  </tr>
</tr>
```

Instead save the HTML as a jQuery object and pull out the id and the innerHTML of the tr element:

```
<% if @success %>
  $('#new-contact-modal').modal('hide');
  let $tmp = $("<%= j render 'contacts/contact_item', contact: @contact %>");
  $(document.getElementById($tmp[0].id)).html($tmp.first().html());
  toastr.info('Contact was successfully updated.', 'info')
<% else %>
  $(".errors").removeClass('hide');
  <% @contact.errors.messages.each do |record| %>
    <% key = record.first %>
    var html = "<%= j get_error(@contact, key) %>";
    $(".error-<%= key.to_s %>").html(html);
  <% end %>
  $('#save-btn').removeAttr("disabled");
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `update.js.erb` is missing `@` infront of `contact`. It should be like this:

`$("tr#contact_item_<%= @contact.id %>").html("<%=j render 'contacts/contact_item', contact: @contact %>");`

2. You need to update `_listing.html.erb` like this:

```
<table class="table" id="contacts">
  <% contacts.each do |contact| %>
    <tr id="contact_item_<%= contact.id %>">
      <%= render partial: 'contacts/contact_item', locals: {contact: contact} %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

3. Then remove `<tr id="contact_item_<%= contact.id %>">` line and the last `</tr>` line from `_contact_item.html.erb`.

That's it.